# How to get specific string value out of a big string in python scripting?

Tags: python, string

I am working upon a python script and i have something as follows:

```
 ['...','name','anbc','date','20/02/2001','path0', 'd://nk/mkn','path1'   
   'k//lk/jjj','path2','f//udfg/jki','path3','hjk//de/lk']
```

So, i want to get my output printing following data:

```
   path0 d://nk/mkn
   path1 k//lk/jjj
   path2 f//udfg/jki
   path4 hjk//de/lk
```

So, how will i get my output like this in my python script?
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate` and `startswith` functions. This would print the element and also the next element only if the first element startswith the string `path`.

```
>>> l =  ['...','name','anbc','date','20/02/2001','path0', 'd://nk/mkn','path1' ,'k//lk/jjj','path2','f//udfg/jki','path3','hjk//de/lk']
>>> for i,j in enumerate(l):
        if j.startswith('path'):
            print(l[i], l[i+1])


path0 d://nk/mkn
path1 k//lk/jjj
path2 f//udfg/jki
path3 hjk//de/lk
>>> len([i for i in l if i.startswith('path')])
4
```

Comment: Ok. and how will i get the total count of the number of paths.e.g if there are many paths like path1,path2,path3,path4,path5 so on and after printing them as u told now i want the total count of path. So ,how will i achieve it?

Comment: You could make the above code as list comp and then apply the length function on the generated list or declare a variable count with initial value as 0 and for each iteration, add 1 to that variable. Finally print the count after the for loop. Sorry commented from mobile.

Comment: @kashyap Did you mean that you may have `path0` several time in your list?

Comment: I mean to get the number of times path got printed on the output. i.e the path counter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function within a list comprehension :

```
>>> l=['...','name','anbc','date','20/02/2001','path0', 'd://nk/mkn','path1'   
...    'k//lk/jjj','path2','f//udfg/jki','path3','hjk//de/lk']

>>> [(i,j) for i,j in zip(l,l[1:]) if i.startswith('path')]
[('path0', 'd://nk/mkn'), ('path1k//lk/jjj', 'path2'), ('path2', 'f//udfg/jki'), ('path3', 'hjk//de/lk')]
```